# Docker is not running when install Laravel

Tags: docker, laravel-8

I have following Laravel docs to get started on Linux using Docker Compose.
The docs I follow is :

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

And the terminal give me massage :

```
Docker is not running.
```

This is first time I use Docker for a project with Laravel. Docker engine and docker compose is installed correctly.
I use Ubuntu 20.04.